# How to create a vertical scroll with tabs inside a bootstrap modal?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, scroll, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal that consists of a set of tabs, I want the tabs to appear in a row through the two symbols I put on the image I can go to the tabs on the right and left, how to do that?
thanks you for your help...

Here is the picture where the tabs look like this,
I want them to be in the same row when I click on the symbols to go to other tabs

[image]

This is my code:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#menu_tab">Menu</button>

 <div class="modal fade" id="menu_tab">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group" id="font" align='right'>
                <div class="form-group" id="font" align='right'>
                    
                    <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
                        <legend class="scheduler-border">Menu</legend>
                            <div class="form-row">                            
                                <div role="tabpanel">

                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">        
                                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" class="active">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Tab1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" class="active">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Tab2" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" class="active">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Tab3" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" class="active">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Tab4" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" class="active">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Tab5" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab5</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" class="active">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Tab6" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab6</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" class="active">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Tab7" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab7</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" class="active">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Tab8" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab8</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item" class="active">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Tab9" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab9</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Tab1" class="active">
                                            <div class="p-3">
                                                tab1 content
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Tab2" class="active">
                                            <div class="p-3">
                                                tab2 content
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Tab3" class="active">
                                            <div class="p-3">
                                                tab3 content
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Tab4" class="active">
                                            <div class="p-3">
                                                tab4 content
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only way to really get them on one row is to reduce the padding on the left and right of each tab or widen the modal window to account for them. Are the arrows just going to go to the next tab or previous tab and will all tabs be on screen at once? If so, I see no real use case for the arrows.

Comment: @OMGDrAcula Thank you very much for your reply but this does not solve my problem I will make the tabs dynamic type in future there will be more

Comment: So the only real thing to do is use flexbox to just let the items flex the space that they need, but eventually there won't be enough room for everything to fit on one row. So you would probably have to widen the modal itself to allow for more space.

Comment: @OMGDrAcula I change the modal to modal-lg my biggest problem is solved, but when I work on it on my phone it becomes two rows, so I have to change it to one row as a vertical scroll

Comment: So for mobile doing the scroll is probably an okay solution but honestly I would just let them wrap on a small screen. You can also try dropping font-size down to 14 and reducing padding etc.

Comment: @OMGDrAcula Thank you very much for your help, I will try to fix it, God willing.

Comment: Good luck! Definitely try adjusting as much as you can to fit